# UpdatePanel AsyncTriggers not working after upgrade to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, asp.net-ajax

Recently, I upgraded my solution to 4.0 and everything seems to have upgraded smoothly but for ASP.NET AJAX.

I have an UpdatePanel like so:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlAdvSearch" UpdateMode="conditional" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>  
      <asp:Button ID="btnHidden" Runat="server" OnClick="btnHidden_Click"
              ClientIDMode="Static"/>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnHidden" EventName="Click"/>
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have a type-ahead textbox which triggers the `btnHidden_Click` event on Click/Enter etc. I'm calling the following method on textbox click/enter.

```
  function getSelectionId() {     
      __doPostBack(
          '<%=btnHidden.ClientID%>',
          document.getElementById('<%=txtLocation.ClientID %>').value
      );
      theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = "";
  }
```

I can see a postback happening and the `Page_Load` executing. However, the server-side `btnHidden_Click` never gets fired. I do not want to disable event-validation at the page-level. What am I doing wrong here? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing on Page_Load.

```
            if (Page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET") == "btnHidden") //Workaround hack for AsyncPostBackTrigger fail
                this.btnHidden_Click(null, null);
```

When an async postback happens, I just fire the event explicitly. Kinda hacky but not worth spending any more time on it :)

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure your assembly is set to target the .NET 4.0 Framework, and then take a look at your web.config file.  You may have a bunch of references to settings that were required to do ASP.NET AJAX operations under ASP.NET 2.0 that you can remove.

Specifically, check the `<compilation>` tag and `<httpHandlers>` tag under `<system.web>` and `system.webServer`.

For example, you might see something like the following under compilation > assemblies:

```
<compilation>
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Those references can most likely be removed.  Also, a bunch of settings under `<pages>`, `<httpHandlers>` and `<httpModules>` can probably be removed as well.

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>
```

Comment: Hey rsbarro, thanks for your reply. I had removed those sections when I did the upgrade. The javascript call goes through as well. Not sure what's breaking though.

Comment: @Praveen So the Updatepanel triggers a postback but the proper event isn't fired?  Does it trigger a full postback or an async postback?